# CSS - Background-size not working on jpg extension

Tags: css, background-size

```
.baner {
    background-image: url('ban.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35%;
    top: 60px;
}
```

Won't do cover on this background but when I do `png` image it works and I don't understand why:

```
.baner {
    background-image: url('ban.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35%;
    top: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works perfectly fine for me, maybe you aren't saving the image probably as `.jpg` or something...

```css
div.one {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-image:url(http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg);
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
div.two {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background-image:url(http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg);
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    
</div>
<div class="two">
    
</div>
```

Comment: @user3187715 - don't forget to click the tick under the reply that you found to be your answer :)

Comment: I didnt know how to click :D Sorry i'm late